# PHP/MySQL Interview - How would you have answered?

Tags: php, mysql

I was asked this interview question so thought I would post it here to see how other users would answer:

`Please write some code which connects to a MySQL database (any host/user/pass), retrieves the current date & time from the database, compares it to the current date & time on the local server (i.e. where the application is running), and reports on the difference. The reporting aspect should be a simple HTML page, so that in theory this script can be put on a web server, set to point to a particular database server, and it would tell us whether the two servers’ times are in sync (or close to being in sync).`

This is what I put:

```
// Connect to database server
$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'xxx';
$dbpass = 'xxx';
$dbname = 'xxx';

$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die (mysql_error());

// Select database
mysql_select_db($dbname) or die(mysql_error());

// Retrieve the current time from the database server
$sql = 'SELECT NOW() AS db_server_time';

// Execute the query
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

// Since query has now completed, get the time of the web server
$php_server_time = date("Y-m-d h:m:s");

// Store query results in an array
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

// Retrieve time result from the array
$db_server_time = $row['db_server_time'];

echo $db_server_time . '<br />';
echo $php_server_time;

if ($php_server_time != $db_server_time) {
    // Server times are not identical

    echo '<p>Database server and web server are not in sync!</p>';

    // Convert the time stamps into seconds since 01/01/1970
    $php_seconds = strtotime($php_server_time);
    $sql_seconds = strtotime($db_server_time);

    // Subtract smaller number from biggest number to avoid getting a negative result
    if ($php_seconds > $sql_seconds) {
        $time_difference = $php_seconds - $sql_seconds;
    }
    else {
        $time_difference = $sql_seconds - $php_seconds;
    } 

    // convert the time difference in seconds to a formatted string displaying hours, minutes and seconds
    $nice_time_difference = gmdate("H:i:s", $time_difference);

    echo '<p>Time difference between the servers is ' . $nice_time_difference;
}
else {
    // Timestamps are exactly the same
    echo '<p>Database server and web server are in sync with each other!</p>';
}
```

Yes, I know that I have used the deprecated mysql_* functions but that aside, how would you have answered, i.e. what changes would you make and why? Are there any factors I have omitted which I should take into consideration?

The interesting thing is that my results always seem to be an exact number of minutes apart when executed on my hosting account:

`2012-12-06 11:47:07`

`2012-12-06 11:12:07`

Comment: If I was the interviewer, I wouldn't have called you back :-)

Comment: Use of DateTime objects, and DateTimeInterval; a little bit of OOP; exception handling for db

Comment: @ruakh yeah, realised that with Jan Dvorak's answer, was a typo on my part, sorry.

Comment: what resources you had to use? pen and paper only?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would have been the bulk of my code:

```
$db = new PDO(...);
$dbTime = new DateTime(current($db->query('SELECT NOW()')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0)));
$myTime = new DateTime();
$diff = $myTime->diff($dbTime);
// do stuff with $diff
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$php_server_time = date("Y-m-d h:m:s");
```

will format the time as year-month-day hour:month:second. This explains the fact the server time seems to be `11:12:07`. It actually says it's december. The database time and the server time differing by exactly 35 minutes would be *very* surprising. It would be surprising even without the word "exactly".

minutes are `i` in the format string.

---

other than that, the times differing by a second do not neccessarily mean the database is out of perfect synchronization with the server. It could just mean some (arbitrarily small) time has passed between the measurements. If you want to verify synchronization, you could make two measurements on the server, one before the query, one after the query, and make a range comparison, or simply delta-compare the times (abs(t1-t2)<=1s)

Comment: oops, my mistake, was a typo in the question, thanks for noticing!

Comment: @martincarlin87 strange you were wondering about the consequences of the typo, indicating the typo is actually in your test code.

Comment: yeah, I was creating the test code from memory, so it was in the test case I ran but I didn't submit it with that typo is what I actually meant.

Comment: @martincarlin87 you should still be able to find your mistake yourself, not wonder about it here ;-)

Comment: thanks Jan but the mistake was only a small part of the question, the main reason I asked is to see what design decisions other people would make.

Comment: @martincarlin87 see the second part of my answer: Your sync logic is flawed.

Answer (score 1):

You handwave away your use of the deprecated `mysql_` functions, but if I were asking that question in a job interview, that would be Red Flag #1.  It would tell me that either you're not keeping up on current best practices in PHP, or you don't care.

The other thing that I'd be concerned about that piece of code is that you're not specifying the format that MySQL gives you the time in.  I'd want to explicitly specify the output format so that you're not relying on any server settings.

Comment: thanks Andy, it's just that in my current role, it's all still `my_sql_*` so I've not had an opportunity to use PDO yet so therefore don't have them memorised either but I do agree with you. About your second point, how would you specify the format of the time returned by MySQL?

Comment: I don't use MySQL, but I'm assuming you'd use the `DATE_FORMAT` function that I found on [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) by Googling for "mysql date format".

Answer (score 0):

would have used PDO and query:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP()
```

in code:

```
$time_difference = abs($PDOStatement->fetchColumn() - date('U'));
```

and probably would declare times "roughly same" when difference is `<= 1`